# How to manage DB connections in a Java Servlet Filter?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I'm writing a traffic auditing servlet filter.

I need to query the database for every HTTP request. There is no connection pool. (I'm adding this filer to the existing application).

I created a JDBC connection object in `init()` method. And made synchronized methods that doing DB query. In 'doFiler()`, I call these synchronized methods 1~2 times.

Can this be big problem?

-- UPDATE --

Not a heavy loaded server.
It runs on single machine. It is serving hundreds KB media files and outgoing bandwidth is 100Mbps, so maximum simultaneous users could be at most 100, I think.

I just wondering.. what's the recommended approach for servlet filters using DB connections.

Comment: And what is the load of your application?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use JNDI resource - you only need to register [JDBC resource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19396-01/819-0215/jdbc.html) and later you may obtain the connection.

Answer (score 0):

why you want to do this in filter? just get the connection in the servlet and release it after you done with it -- it is enough for your load, and simple enough.